# Flask: can't get redirection to work when using openCV

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, opencv, flask

I am using opencv and pyzbar to make a barcode scanner that can work in a flask app.
There is a while True loop which constantly outputs the current camera frame to 127.0.0.1:5000/scanner, whilst simultaneously attempting to decode a barcode from the image. If it decodes a barcode, the loop breaks and the program redirects to 127.0.0.1:5000/output/, where the barcode number is displayed - except it doesn't for some reason. 127.0.0.1:5000/output/ displays correctly if it is entered manually.

**Python:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, redirect, url_for
import io
import cv2
import sys
from pyzbar import pyzbar

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/output/')
def output():
    return str(output)

@app.route('/scanner')
def index():
    return render_template('scanner.html')

def gen():
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        read_return_code, frame = vc.read()
        og = frame
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(200,170),(450,330),(0,255,100),7)
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        decode = pyzbar.decode(og)
        if len(str(decode)) > 10:
            global output
            output = str(decode).split("'")
            output = output[1]
            vc.release()
            return redirect('/output/')   #THE PROBLEM 
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
      
        encode_return_code, image_buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        io_buf = io.BytesIO(image_buffer)
        print("a", file=sys.stderr)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + io_buf.read() + b'\r\n')

        
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(
        gen(),
        mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=False)
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
} 
</style>
<title>Scanner</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Scanner</h1>
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you return redirect without parameters, this is equal to just requesting it via URL.
2. your 'output' route doesn't take any input params.
   You should change your code to something like this, where 'data' is the output of your cv:

```py
    app.route('/output/<data>')
    def output(data):
        return str(data)
        
    app.route('/scanner')
    def index():
        data='whatever'
        return redirect(url_for('output', data=data))
```